# By taking the public relations offensive - meaning

Tags: grammar, word-usage

> **By taking the public relations offensive**, the Russians have time and again been two steps ahead. U.S. and Western officials, not to mention the Kiev government, are left scrambling to debunk the rumors and fear-mongering. As a result they are frequently playing catchup for hearts and minds in the east.

How do you understand the phrase in a bold-type font? Does it mean that they take them (the public relations) as an offensive thing, they perceive the public relations as an offense to them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a modification of the idiom

> taking the offensive

which is related to

> going on the offensive.

It means that the Russians' PR team is pre-emptively "attacking" (which is this case means communicating their position with media outlets) to force any opposing viewpoint into a defensive posture, which the quote you provided explains plainly as being "left scrambling to debunk the rumors and fear-mongering."

Answer (score 2):

In this context it means they are **proactively using public relations** to forward their position.